# Are rebuttal papers too narrow in scope to get published, and is there an alternative?

Tags: publications, publishability

When reading a recent philosophy paper I spotted what I believe to be a subtle error in one of the assumptions their main argument relies on. I am not exactly an active participant in academia, so I seek some perspective.

What is the customary way to bring up this kind of observation? Is it a paper submitted to the same journal the original paper was published in?

It seems to me that this kind of rebuttal paper would naturally be quite narrow and possibly quite short, too. Do journals go for that kind of papers? I'd quite like to participate in the discussion the paper in question is part of, and I definitely wouldn't mind submitting a paper of my own, but the narrowness of the scope for the rebuttal paper makes me wonder if it is overreaching.

Comment: The nice thing to do would be to write to the authors first. You can also / subsequently / instead post your comments on [pubpeer](https://pubpeer.com/).

Comment: As a sidenote, when criticising published work in a formal paper you should be a lot more sure than "I believe". The first step would be to validate that this is indeed an error, including communicating with the author and other experts in the field to ensure that you aren't just misunderstanding.

Comment: You could look into whether the journal publishes a suitable content type. Might be titled comment, reply, or something similar.

Comment: It is important to note that there is a distinction between an error and a legitimate difference in opinion. This is fairly clear in hard sciences, but in fields like philosophy, you need to understand the norms of the field, and for that you need to work with somebody with experience in academia.

Comment: I published something like a rebuttal, or rather a correction, of somebody's paper once. On another occasion, I prepared a technical report with a critique of somebody's results that wasn't published, although I'm considering making a very subtle published version of it. In my case, I don't see a necessity for something like that to be published in a peer-reviewed journal. I could as well publish a report or submit a paper to arXiv. I realise that your preferences and circumstances may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuttals, critiques, commentaries, letters, reply get published. They are handled differently across journals.

> What is the customary way to bring up this kind of observation?

Approach varies across fields and policies of each journal

- correspondence
- letter to editor
- discourse
- rebuttal, critique, commentary

An approach is to engage the author(s) as professional colleagues. This can be by politely and scientifically pointing out the '*error*' and how to rectify.

Another is to write to the editor in similitude to the type one would have written to the author(s).

There are platforms that enables engagement on articles such as [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/). When using PubPeer, one might want to take note of

- [Barbour and Stell (2020)](https://direct.mit.edu/books/oa-edited-volume/4598/chapter/211141/PubPeer-Scientific-Assessment-Without-Metrics)
- [Ortega (2022)](https://asistdl.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/asi.24568)

Talking of platforms, journals and research communities are providing platforms for readers to engage on articles. See for instance [this on critical realism](https://criticalrealismnetwork.org/2022/07/06/maybe-two-parts-of-reality-instead-of-three/comment-page-1/#comment-187) and [AIS elibrary](https://aisel.aisnet.org/) which allows commenting across many of its published articles.

> Is it a paper submitted to the same journal the original paper was published in?

As alluded to, some journals are welcoming of critiques while some ain't. The wordings use and the categories varies. Rebuttal was used in [Green and Krasno (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2111451). Mingers used critique in his *rebuttal* of Demetis while [Demetis and Lee used commentary in their reply](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1471772717301720).

It is not unusual for commentary having different meaning across journals, hence journals tends to define and/or provided guidelines. A case in point [International journal of qualitative studies on health and well-being](https://doi.org/10.3402%2Fqhw.v11.31390)

[Reference]
[Green, D. P., & Krasno, J. S. (1990). Rebuttal to Jacobson's" New evidence for old arguments". *American Journal of Political Science*, 34(2), 363-372](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2111451)

[Demetis, D. S., & Lee, A. S. (2017). Taking the first step with systems theorizing in information systems: A response. Information and Organization, 27(3), 163-170](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1471772717301720)

[Berterö, C. (2016). Guidelines for writing a commentary. *International journal of qualitative studies on health and well-being*, 11(1), 31390](https://doi.org/10.3402%2Fqhw.v11.31390)

---

[Barbour, B., & Stell, B. M. (2020). PubPeer: Scientific assessment without metrics. Gaming the metrics: Misconduct and manipulation in academic research, 149-155](https://direct.mit.edu/books/oa-edited-volume/4598/chapter/211141/PubPeer-Scientific-Assessment-Without-Metrics)

[Ortega, J. L. (2022). Classification and analysis of PubPeer comments: How a web journal club is used. Journal of the Association for Information Science and Technology, 73(5), 655-670](https://asistdl.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/asi.24568)